# nginx with Self Signed Certificate and iOS development

Tags: ios, https, ssl-certificate

I use nginx with self signed certificate to serve and save some data from my iOS application. I want to know if Apple will reject it because of my self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Apple already approved my app. So there is no problem when using nginx with self signed certificate.